# Contact details are not updated on Google Assistant page

Tags: google-smart-home

I've updated Contact details on https://console.actions.google.com/ -> Deploy -> Directory information. I can see them there. But I can't see updated info on the Google Assistant page (https://assistant.google.com/ -> explore actions).

How this issue could be fixed?

Does Google Assistant page update all info mentioned on Directory information tab at the same time?

Comment: Assuming your Action has already been reviewed and published to production, these adjustments can be made manually by the certification team. You can file a request in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1319401).

Comment: @devunwired Does it mean we are not able to test all the info from Directory information from user's perspective before publishing to production?

Answer (score 0):

Every action needs to be reviewed before being published to production so that might be the reason the Assistant page doesn’t show the updated information. You can reach out to the certification team by creating a support ticket and coordinate your contact detail change.

You can find more information about publishing your smart Home Action at https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/directory-information